# Calling functions on columns of data in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have column-formatted data and I want to make a splot of the logarithm of the 5th column versus the first two columns.  I have tried:

```
set pm3d map
splot "thing.file" u 1:2:log($5)
```

But I get the error

```
undefined value
```

How can I get gnuplot to plot a function of one of the columns of data?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This works:

```
splot "thing.file" u 1:2:(log($5))
```

In general, if a term is defined by a function of a column in a data file rather than the column itself, there need to be parentheses around that term.

Answer (score 7):

To extend the solution,  you can use multiple columns if your function requires multiple inputs:
example:

```
plot "file" using 1:(x=$2, y=$3, f(x,y))
```

also works.

Comment: A  note to noobs like me. In gnu plot, while writing a function, one doesn't write x^y but x**y. I was making this mistake.

Answer (score -7):

Taken from gnuplot's own [FAQ](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/faq.html#SECTION00074000000000000000) ,  "Gnuplot has been and is a plotting program,not a data processing or mathematical program suite. Therefore gnuplot can't do that.".

You can run your data file through Octave or Matlab to generate the log files before plotting.

Comment: Figured it out:

If I enter:

    splot "thing.file" u 1:2:(log($5))
it runs the function on that column.  In general, there need to be parentheses around an expression involving functions of a column, I think.

Comment: @Dan Why not make that an answer?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question until 8 hours after I post it.